# intrinsic vs mutex lock

Tags: java, synchronization

Looking at the implementation of [Collection's SynchronizedList](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Collections.java#Collections.SynchronizedCollection) i recognized that all access on the internal list is synchronized by locking on the wrapper's final member "mutex". As all access is synchronized on the same object, why dont we ommit the extra mutex object and just synchronize on the list itself? Is it only because of the fact that anybody else could synchronize on that list and we might get deadlocks? 
I am asking, because i consider to implement a container-class, that holds two lists. 
The container offers e.g. .addToL1(...) and .addToL2(...). In this case the inner lists are not accessible, so it should be sufficient to synchronize on the lists intrinsically, correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most robust solution is to lock on an object that the caller has no way of getting access to. (We will ignore reflection and Unsafe for a moment) The JDK developers have to consider the worst thing any developer could do with the library because someone will do that and things they couldn't have thought of.

However, sometimes simplicity is the most important driver esp if you know who will be using it and understand its limitations.

Comment: So you want to tell me that, in fact, there is no difference (in threading, so to say) between locking on the object, i am going to access itself, or another object. The only difference is the problem of the "stupid user".

Comment: @user2504380 from a performance/threading point of view, it doesn't matter which lock you lock as long as it is consistent.

Answer (score 2):

In this case it is specifically done because sublists created from the list have to synchronize on the parent object

```
 public List<E> subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
        synchronized(mutex) {
            return new SynchronizedList<E>(list.subList(fromIndex, toIndex),
                                        mutex);
        }
    }
```

If you create your synchronized list by `Collections.synchronizedList( list );`, it will set the mutex to `this` (that is, the synchronized list object itself).

But you can also call `Collections.synchronizedList()` with two parameters, the second of which will then be used as the mutex.

And as in general it isn't a good idea to synchronize on publicly visible objects, I prefer to always use the 2 parameter version and hide the mutex object from clients of the code.

Comment: My headline is in fact confusing: So you would finally agree?  "The container offers e.g. .addToL1(...) and .addToL2(...). In this case the inner lists are not accessible, so it should be sufficient to synchronize on the lists intrinsically, correct?"

Comment: @user2504380 If the two lists are independent of each other, then yes. But there's really nothing to gain from it, it's just as easy to create a `private final Object lock = new Object()` and lock on it.